# Recognize the duration time (start, stop) when user answers a incoming/outgoing call

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

Can i recognize the start time and end time of duration call when user answers incoming and outgoing call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are events you can track when your app is running and you get an incoming call or alarm or any other system related popup.

**there is no exact way to say if it's a call, alarm or other system application hiding your app. The events are called Obscured and Unobscured:**

msdn link obscured event: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.controls.phoneapplicationframe.obscured(v=vs.105).aspx

Example on Nokia wiki on how to implement this:
http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/How_to_handle_phone_calls_and_other_interruptions_in_Windows_Phone